# Onclick fadeout div

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So I wanted to fade out a div after onclick, as I am making a game where you have to create random circles. The problem with my code is that after it fades out it reappears! (Also, It doesn't have to fade out just disappear after onclick) Here is my code:

```js
function fade() {
  document.getElementById('circle').style.animation="fadeout 1s"
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeout {
  1% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: none;
  }
}

.fadeout {
  animation: fadeout 1s
}

.circle {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Aim</title>
    <div onclick="fade()" id="circle" class="circle"></div>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution and goes well. Look at the changes.  Good Luck!

```js
function fade() {
  document.getElementById('circle').style.animation="fadeout 1s forwards"   //change this part
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeout {
  1% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;   //change this part
  }
}

.fadeout {
  animation: fadeout 1s
}

.circle {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Aim</title>
    <div onclick="fade()" id="circle" class="circle"></div>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `display` property of `div` to `none` after the animation is Completed.

```js
    function fade() {
    document.getElementById('circle').style.animation="fadeout 1s";
    setTimeout(() => {    document.getElementById('circle').style.display="none";},1000)
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it this way... just replace `visibility:hidden` in your css with `display:none`. That's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a transition to the circle and set the opacity to 0 in js. I would also offer that you can use mouseclick to make its opacity 1 again and reappear wherever you click at.

```js
function fade() {
  document.getElementById('circle').style.opacity="0"
}
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Aim</title>
    <div onclick="fade()" id="circle" class="circle"></div>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```